# Symfony Hidden fields

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm new to symfony and have followed this amazing tutorial to setup my bundle and and entitys using the the command  line using doctrine via the console.

http://symfony.com/blog/symfony2-getting-easier-interactive-generators

the only issue is that the class I have setup has hidden fields. for example date created and date updated. This is just for my records so I can see if people have been doing things they shouldn't have.

the only issue is they are showing on the front end and I don't know how to hide them, without rewriting the code that was generated and adding the fields one by one.

Here is the function in the controller

```
public function createAction(Request $request)
{
    $entity = new Client();
    $form = $this->createCreateForm($entity);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isValid()) {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($entity);
        $em->flush();

        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('client_show', array('id' => $entity->getId())));
    }

    return $this->render('AcmeClientMoodBundle:Client:new.html.twig', array(
        'entity' => $entity,
        'form'   => $form->createView(),
    ));
}

/**
* Creates a form to create a Client entity.
*
* @param Client $entity The entity
*
* @return \Symfony\Component\Form\Form The form
*/
private function createCreateForm(Client $entity)
{      
    $form = $this->createForm(new ClientType(), $entity, array(
        'action' => $this->generateUrl('client_create'),
        'method' => 'POST',
    ));

    $form->add('submit', 'submit', array('label' => 'Create'));

    return $form;
}
```

and here is the entity/class

```
namespace Acme\ClientMoodBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;

/**
 * Client
 */
class Client
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $logo;

    /**
     * @var integer
     */
    private $moodId;

    /**
     * @var integer
     */
    private $projectManagerId;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     */
    private $created;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     */
    private $updated;

    /**
     * @var integer
     */
    private $active;


    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set name
     *
     * @param string $name
     * @return Client
     */
    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get name
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    /**
     * Set logo
     *
     * @param string $logo
     * @return Client
     */
    public function setLogo($logo)
    {
        $this->logo = $logo;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get logo
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getLogo()
    {
        return $this->logo;
    }

    /**
     * Set moodId
     *
     * @param integer $moodId
     * @return Client
     */
    public function setMoodId($moodId)
    {
        $this->moodId = $moodId;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get moodId
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getMoodId()
    {
        return $this->moodId;
    }

    /**
     * Set projectManagerId
     *
     * @param integer $projectManagerId
     * @return Client
     */
    public function setProjectManagerId($projectManagerId)
    {
        $this->projectManagerId = $projectManagerId;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get projectManagerId
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getProjectManagerId()
    {
        return $this->projectManagerId;
    }

    /**
     * Set created
     *
     * @param \DateTime $created
     * @return Client
     */
    public function setCreated($created)
    {
        $this->created = $created;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get created
     *
     * @return \DateTime
     */
    public function getCreated()
    {
        return $this->created;
    }

    /**
     * Set updated
     *
     * @param \DateTime $updated
     * @return Client
     */
    public function setUpdated($updated)
    {
        $this->updated = $updated;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get updated
     *
     * @return \DateTime
     */
    public function getUpdated()
    {
        return $this->updated;
    }

    /**
     * Set active
     *
     * @param integer $active
     * @return Client
     */
    public function setActive($active)
    {
        $this->active = $active;

        return $this;
    }
```

How is the best way  to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

You should look into your class `ClientType` and remove the fields you don't want.

Field creation looks like :

```
$builder->add('created');
```

Remove this line.

Comment: Woo that is so easy. I love symfony! thanks for your fast response.

Comment: One last thing how would I pass the date variable to the database.

EG: the below message, I will need to pass some thing like this $date->format('d-m-Y H:i:s');

'INSERT INTO Client (name, logo, mood_id, project_manager_id, created, updated, active) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)' with params ["Test", "\/logo.jpg", 1, 1, null, null, true]:

Comment: Before persisting the entity, you have to use something like `$entity->setCreated(new \Datetime("now"));`

Comment: I invite you to read [this section of the documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html#lifecycle-callbacks). The example is exactly what you need.